# Problem with background images on table cells between different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a design in css when displayed in Firefox appears correctly. But when opened with Firefox or Chrome there is a problem with the background images of the cells.

The problem is that cells with background images are elongated. I not sure how to fix this. I have defined the size of the cells but the Chrome and Explorer table do not respect this value.

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="463px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" >
            <img src="images/principal.gif" border="0" lenght="1037px" height="463px"  />
        </td>
        <td height="146px" id="celda" style="padding:15px;background-image:url(images/capdreta.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat; border:0;" >
            <p class="titol"> Anuncio Publicitario</p><br />
            <p class="text">Inserte un anuncio <br/>publicitario en tu app</p> <br />
            <a href="#">Más Información</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/iadd.gif" border="0"/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="111px" id="celda" style="padding:15px;background-image:url(images/spacegris.gif);background-repeat:">
            <p class="titol"> Anuncio Publicitario</p><br/>
            <p class="text"> Inserte un anuncio <br/>
            publicitario en tu app</p><br />
            <a href="#">Más Información</a>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="90"><img src="images/rss.gif" border="0"/></td>         
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does it work correctly or not with ff? Your saying both. And providing css/html sample would help.

Comment: It work correctly with ff. The version is css3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Let me give you some hints to make sure your question gets the attention it deserves: (1) Format your code. People are more likely to read well-formatted code. (2) Create a minimal, working example that reproduces the issue. Remove everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Francesc : "in firefox appears correctly. But when opened with firefox or chrome are prblem with background images of cells.", do you mean "with **IE** or chrome are problem" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<img>` tag should have the property `width` instead of `lenght` (which doesn't exist)

See the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arnley/WVJss/)** (images won't work of course since I don't have their URLs)